# Проблемы с получением списка ранее подключенных устройств Bluetooth android?

Tags: android

Я делаю приложение которое работает с другим устройством по Bluetooth. Для того что-бы начать передавать и получать данные с другого устройства мне необходимо к нему подключится. Данное устройство уже есть в списке подключенных устройств в меню настроек Bluetooth. Но теперь мне нужно получить этот список и у себя в приложении. Для этих целей я создал свой ListView в котором должны отображаться имена(возможно с адресами) всех ранее подключенных устройств. Я создал класс для одного объекта:

```
public class DataModel {
    private String name;


    public DataModel(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

}
```

далее создал адаптер:

```
public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<DataModel> implements View.OnClickListener {
    private ArrayList<DataModel> dataSet;
    private Context mContext;

    public static class ViewHolder {
        TextView tvName;
    }

    public ListAdapter(ArrayList<DataModel> data, Context context) {
        super(context, R.layout.row_item, data);
        this.dataSet = data;
        this.mContext = context;


    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        int position = (Integer) view.getTag();
        Object object = getItem(position);
        DataModel dataModel = (DataModel) object;

        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.name:
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Name"+ Objects.requireNonNull(dataModel).getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                /*Snackbar.make(view, "Name " + dataModel.getName(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("No action", null).show();*/
                break;
        }
    }

    private int lastPosition = -1;

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        // Get the data item for this position
        DataModel dataModel = getItem(position);
        // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
        ViewHolder viewHolder; // view lookup cache stored in tag

        final View result;
        if (convertView == null) {

            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_item, parent, false);
            viewHolder.tvName = convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);

            result = convertView;

            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            result = convertView;
        }

        Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext, (position > lastPosition) ? R.anim.up_from_bottom : R.anim.down_from_top);
        result.startAnimation(animation);
        lastPosition = position;

        viewHolder.tvName.setText(Objects.requireNonNull(dataModel).getName());
        // Return the completed view to render on screen

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

и наконец мне нужно инициализировать список в классе `MainActivity`:

```
Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = bluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();

        if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
            // There are paired devices. Get the name and address of each paired device.
            for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {
                final String deviceName = device.getName();

                listView = findViewById(R.id.pairlist);
                List<DataModel> data = new ArrayList<>();
                for (int i=0;i<deviceName.length();i++)
                {
                    data.add(new DataModel(deviceName[i]));
                }
                adapter = new ListAdapter(data, getApplicationContext());
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);

                listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
                        BluetoothDevice device = (BluetoothDevice) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position);
                        myThreadConnectBTdevice = new ThreadConnectBTdevice(device);
                        myThreadConnectBTdevice.start();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
```

так как я создал класс для одного объекта списка, мне нужно создать массив этих объектов который и будет отображаться в моем списке. Я пробовал эту строку - `final String deviceName = device.getName();` привести к типу `array` то есть сделать массив имен устройств. Но у меня почему-то не получилось это сделать. Вероятнее всего я что-то не учел. Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нужно вынести за пределы цикла создание списка, адаптера и т.п., а внутри делать только то, что связано с обработкой одного элемента списка:

```
    Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = bluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();

    if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
        listView = findViewById(R.id.pairlist);
        List<DataModel> data = new ArrayList<>();

        // There are paired devices. Get the name and address of each paired device.
        for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {
            final String deviceName = device.getName();
            data.add(new DataModel(deviceName));
        }

        adapter = new ListAdapter(data, getApplicationContext());
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
                BluetoothDevice device = (BluetoothDevice) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position);
                myThreadConnectBTdevice = new ThreadConnectBTdevice(device);
                myThreadConnectBTdevice.start();
            }
        });
    }
```

P.S. Что бы использовать как модель непосредственно `BluetoothDevice` нужно типизировать адаптер под `BluetoothDevice` (все упоминания `DataModel` в классе адаптера заменить на `BluetoothDevice`) и список, соответственно, заполнить ими же:

```
        List<BluetoothDevice> data = new ArrayList<>();

        for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {
            data.add(device );
        }
```

Соответственно элементом списка теперь является `BluetoothDevice` и можно брать из него нужные данные напрямую

Comment: а при нажатии на элемент мы получаем только имя устройства я так понял? просто мне нужно передавать адрес того устройства к которому я хочу подключится.

Comment: Или дополните Ваш `DataModel` нужными данными, или используйте вместо него непосредственно `BluetoothDevice`. `onItemClick` в Вашем коде, кстати, на второй вариант и рассчитан.

Comment: не могли бы вы поподробнее объяснить второй вариант, просто на данный момент если использовать список и инициализацию которые я создал то `device` не может быть `cast` к `BluetoothDevice`, я так понял что на данный момент `device` это переменная `string` и у меня при нажатии на элемент списка приложение слетает с ошибкой.

Comment: согласно дополнению вашего ответа, нам класс `DataModel` вообще не нужен?

Comment: Ну да, не нужен. Моделью у нас будет класс `BluetoothDevice`